# Conditional where clause in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a query in `APEX`, which uses a where clause condition based on a item's value in apex. If the date is `null` then I want to show all the records from the table, and if the date is not `null` i want to add where conditions based on that value. How can I do that ?

I want to add below 2 conditions if the `P2_SELECT_DATE` is not null :

```
select * from HR_DATA
where 
     :P2_SELECT_DATE between  person_eff_start_date and person_eff_end_date
 and :P2_SELECT_DATE between nvl(assign_eff_start_date,sysdate-1) and nvl(assign_eff_end_date, sysdate+1)
```

And if the `P2_SELECT_DATE` is null then I don't want to have these conditions in the where clause at all.

Comment: Cant you just use a or? `where value is null  or (value = 4 and othervalue = 'justinthiscase')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select * from HR_DATA
where (:P2_SELECT_DATE is null
      or (:P2_SELECT_DATE between person_eff_start_date and person_eff_end_date
         and :P2_SELECT_DATE between nvl(assign_eff_start_date,sysdate-1) 
                                 and nvl(assign_eff_end_date, sysdate+1)
      )
```

Sometimes if there are a lot of optional filters it can be more efficient to build the query dynamically:

```
declare
    q long;
begin    
    q := 'select * from HR_DATA where 1=1';

    if :P2_SELECT_DATE is null then
       q := q || ' and :P2_SELECT_DATE between person_eff_start_date and person_eff_end_date'
              || ' and :P2_SELECT_DATE between nvl(assign_eff_start_date,sysdate-1)'
              || ' and nvl(assign_eff_end_date, sysdate+1);
    end if;
    return q;
end;
```

The "where 1=1" is just a trick so that any conditionally appended filters alsways start with " and".

Comment: Oh yes..This appears to be a good solution , but is there any way I can do it just in the query..without any plsql block.

Comment: No, without PL/SQL you must use a static SQL query as in my first code block.